# Ubuntu crashes abnormally

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, crash, intel-graphics

I'm using [Ubuntu 17.04 32-bit edition](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso) and it crashes when I do some rendering in blender and also when I press add track for motion tracking.

My system configuration is as follows:

- Intel® core™ i3-3210 CPU @3.20GHz × 4
- 2 GB ram
- Graphics: intel® ivybridge Desktop ×86/MMX/SSE2
- OS: ubuntu 17.04 32-bit
- Swap size: 1GB

I don't have any graphic card but it shows something in *All Settings → Details*, on Windows I saw "Intel HD graphics" there.

Here's the `free -h` output from the terminal while running blender as asked by @ByteCommander:

```
         Total    used    free    shared   buff/cache    available
 Mem:     1.7G    619M    423M      219M      663M         680M
Swap:     975M      0B    975M
```

When Ubuntu crashes, it takes me to somewhere where it asks to choose an operating system, one of it is "recovery mode". Whatever I choose from them, it takes me to a terminal like something and prints loads of errors. If I leave the PC for some hours, it's still doing something, also printing something:

```
Busybox 1.x type help to get a list of built in commands
 initframs:_
```

This morning, blender freezes again (4th time in 4 days) and crashes after it, then Ubuntu freezes, doesn't respond to clicks, suddenly restarts and finally takes me to the black screen, printing:

```
[4521.250846] EXT4-fs error (device sda5): 
        ext4_final_entry:1463 inode #8519685: comm upowered: 
        reading directory iblock 0
```

This message is sticked on 38th line of my screen and it's over 5 hours from then. What is it reading for so long?. To solve this I reinstalled again and again.

Shall I use Windows again instead, because I have animated some models in blender (on Windows) but in Ubuntu I end up with a crash even when just copying contents of a DVD to system.

Ubuntu login screen doesn't ask for password sometimes and lets anybody in to my desktop.

Also if this is a graphics card problem, what card would you recommend of 4GB which will work on blender, as blender is not supported by many graphic cards.

Comment: I guess that the crashes when you run blender could be out-of-memory problems. How much swap do you have? Which release of Ubuntu is it btw. and which desktop environment? Can you please copy the output of `free -h` from a terminal while you are running blender and [edit] your question to paste it here as plain text? - About the boot sector issue you mentioned, you have to be more detailed and show us exactly what you got displayed. We can't read minds yet.

Comment: You haven't described any troubleshooting, you can't tell us what error message you get when it crashes, you didn't tell us what version of ubuntu you are using, you say the pc has no graphics card, you assert that linux "doesnt have a good relation" with intel drivers (but offer no justification for your opinion). Are you looking for help here or just using this as a forum to complain?

Comment: @Byte Commander i edited my question and given some details of free - h command in terminal, sorry for the formatting mistake, i wrote that on my phone hope you can read that clearly.

Comment: Thanks, I suggested an edit to improve your post a bit regarding formatting and readability. Unfortunately I don't know how to proceed with your issues from here. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like a hardware failure with memory or disk. Reinstalling "again and again" won't help; at worst it will mask the underlying problem for longer, allowing more of your files to become corrupted. You need to run some diagnostics on the disk and memory.

Comment: @roaima I dont think it's a hardware problem, because it performs better in windows, i switched to ubuntu because i've heard some peoples claiming blender is better on linux, when i was using windows, i made a dog with armature and fur, moving it's tail and looking in the camera etc. but if i try to do it now, the blender crashes, i think it's time to install windows again, right? .

Comment: Out of interest why are you using the 32bit install instead of the 64bit one? Your i3 is a 64bit chip.

Comment: @roaima because i have 2gb of Ram, i read an article saying 64-bit must be used when your ram size is larger than 4gb, else it is not necessary.

Comment: In order to progress this I think you need to provide some details. What error messages? Have you checked the SMART status on the disk? Have you run `memtest86` or equivalent to confirm there is no memory fault? What do you see on the screen when the system crashes! Are you sure it's an os crash and not an application crash? Why?